# Printing field names of any wished class

Tags: c#

Assume that we have some classes not having common interface or base class. How can we obtain names of the class wished? Is it possible? I’ve found *the following code working as expected*. However, I want to use it in a function by passing a class name. Is there any other way to achieve that?

```
 MemberInfo[] members = typeof(objectWhatever).GetMembers();
 foreach (MemberInfo memberInfo in members.Where(p => p.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property))
 {
      Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", memberInfo.Name); // Name: MyField
 }
```

I tried to write the following, but *not working syntactically*.

```
 public static List<string> FieldNames(object obj ,string className)
 {
     dynamic changedObj = Convert.ChangeType(obj, Type.GetType(className));

     MemberInfo[] members = typeof(changedObj).GetMembers();

     foreach (MemberInfo memberInfo in members.Where(p => p.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property))
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", memberInfo.Name); // Name: MyField
     }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `dynamic`.

Comment: Wait a minute, so you attempt to convert obj to be of type className, so that you could get the Type object from changedObj again, the very same Type object you already provided to `Convert.ChangeType`... what? I feel like i am missing a part of the puzzle here that would explain why you attempted to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we have to find `Type` by given name, e.g.

```
// className either in short format: "Form" or
//                  in full  format: "System.Windows.Forms.Form"
private static Type TypeFromName(string className)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(className))
    return null;

  return AppDomain
    .CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(asm => asm.GetTypes())
    .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == className || t.Namespace + "." + t.Name == className);
}
```

Then we are ready to enumerate *properties*: the only difference is that we use `tp` - `Type` *found* instead of *hardcoded* `typeof(objectWhatever)`

```
 string className = ...

 Type tp = TypeFromName(className);

 if (tp != null)
 {
     var members = tp
       .GetMembers()
       .Where(p => p.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property);

     foreach (MemberInfo memberInfo in members)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", memberInfo.Name); 
     }
 }
 else 
 {
     // className has not been found
 }
```

Comment: I would like to have your experience at my age but I know it is not possible. It works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: @snr: I suggest using *Reflection* and *Linq*: with a help of Reflection we get `Property/FieldInfo`, which we then query by *Linq*.

Comment: Sir, would you mind glancing at the following question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59550456/assignment-same-property-values-to-other

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want:

```
MemberInfo[] members = Type.GetType(className).GetMembers();
```

`typeof()` only works with a known compile-time type - like `typeof(string)` or `typeof(T)` for generic types.

You also don't need to *change* the type of `obj` to view the values of its members using reflection, if that's where you're going with this.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Type.GetType(...) returned null.

Comment: @snr Then you're passing in a `className` value that can't be resolved to a type. Converting string names to types can be tricky, especially when you are using types from other assemblies. I'd encourage you to do some more research on the subject.